# Download all secret links from a map design website

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

There is a website which shows links on a map (map layer currently can't be shown but links can be shown as points).
To view this website, this must be followed: (Pictures 1-2-3 also shows the way)

Firstly, click this website 'http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx', [image: (Picture 1)]

Secondly, choose '15. Kizilirmak Havzasi' from 'Havza' tab, [image: Picture 2]

Finally, click 'sorgula' bottom. [image: Picture 3]

After the final stage, you should view the website ('http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/HaritaNew.aspx') where the points can be shown on a map. [image: Picture 4]

Normally, I can use selenium to download web pages or can grab all links using different libraries. However, these methods can't obtain the links because they are embedded almost in a secret way.

I would like to download all the links that these points have.

For example, this script doesn't continue after 'parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle' line. I don't know why?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza")).select_by_visible_text("15. Kizilirmak Havzasi")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_btnListele").click()
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
all_urls = []
all_images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'OL_Icon')]/img")
for image in all_images :
     image.click()
     for handle in driver.window_handles :
          if handle != parent_handle:
              driver.switch_to_window(handle)
              WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
              all_urls.append(driver.current_url)
              driver.close()
              driver.switchTo.window(parent_handle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not click them one by one and then get the URL of the opened window, using `driver.getCurrentUrl()`?

In the below code, first I wait for all the images and then perform the click action using ActionChains class since the normal Selenium `click()` wasn't working.

Complete code in Python -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Test automation\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza")).select_by_visible_text("15. Kizilirmak Havzasi")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_btnListele").click()
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.maximize_window()
all_urls = []
all_images = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@id,'OL_Icon')]/img")))
print len(all_images)
for image in all_images :
     webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(image).click(image).perform()
     for handle in driver.window_handles :
          if handle != parent_handle:
              driver.switch_to_window(handle)
              WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
              all_urls.append(driver.current_url)
              driver.close()
              driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)

print all_urls
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It can't find inner urls in the icon images in the website.

Comment: Clicking on one of the icons, the script in answer will give the URL which the icon redirects in the new window. For ex,, one of them  is - http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Bilgi.aspx?istasyon=D15A161%20BOZKIR%20ACISU. If not this, what do you want to scrape?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want, but your script doesn't work to scrape. I edited my question. Please look at my script above. I don't know what the wrong is.

Comment: @f.yunusemreCevahir Please check my updated answer. The script ran successfully and gave me the urls.

Comment: Since, I spend a considerable amount on this, kindly accept my answer by clicking the tick mark ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't even know this tick existing. :) I did now. Thank you, again